# Can a TrueCrypt Hidden OS volume be larger than the system volume?

Tags: truecrypt

I am trying to set up a TrueCrypt hidden OS with as much space available in it as possible. I have a 100 GB hard drive which I have partitioned into a 10 GB C: drive with windows installed and a 100GB second partition. I created a TrueCrypt Hidden OS and copied about 15 GB of data to the Outer volume. I formatted both Outer and Inner as FAT32. I expected that the Hidden volume would be nearly 85GB, but when I was finished it was only 10GB just like my C: drive, and I am now unable to use most of my 100GB drive.

What am I doing wrong? I didn't see any settings for the size of the hidden OS. How do I create a Hidden OS with more hidden storage space than the decoy OS?

Here is a screenshot of the partition layout:

[image: screenshot]

C: will be the decoy OS.
E: will be the Outer Volume. I want a hidden OS inside E that is greater than 9.54 GB.

Comment: The container is only 20GB so the operating system installed within the container ( the hiddne partition ) is only 20GB.  You would have to provide more space for the hidden partition if you wanted more space.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @Ramhound. The outer volume is 100 GB. TrueCrypt is making the Hidden volume 20 GB to match the system partition, but there is a lot more space available. How do I provide more space as you suggest?

Comment: You said you made a 20GB partition.  You need to extend that partition if you want more space.

Comment: That's the decoy OS partition. SO you're saying that the answer to my question is, "You can't, the TrueCrypt Hidden OS volume must be the same size as the first partition, the decoy OS partition"?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the layout of your actual hdd for us?  Just post the link I will add it to your question.

Comment: @Ramhound added a screenshot to the question

Comment: There is no reason the hidden OS on E would be limited to only 10GB.

Comment: I'm confused.  The outer and hidden volume are on the same partition, that's the whole point of having the hidden partition, it lies "within" another outer partition.  You seem to be wanting to make your hidden partiton on a separate partition which isn't possible and doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ultrasawblade: Yes, the outer volume is on E, and the hidden volume is hidden inside the outer volume. I don't want my hidden volume on a separate partition, I want it on the same partition as the outer volume, E:

Comment: @Ramhound I know, I am confused as to why my hidden OS partition is only 9.54 GB. TrueCrypt never asked me how large to make it; it just defaulted to the size of C: my system drive. Can I change this somehow?

Comment: @user231750 - You willing to adjust the two partitions to see if by doing so TrueCrypt provides you with more space? You sure you didn't accidently install the os on C instead of the hidden partition within E? Have you read the following article. I admit I thought you were talking about an os within a TrueCrypt container at first. http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/hidden-operating-system can you also provide the same screenshot from within hidden OS?  This will tell me if the system parition can be expanded.

Comment: I am willing to make any adjustments, this is a test VM before I do it for real. But wait, what @Ramhound? Yes, the OS is on C: now. I am going into TrueCrypt and making a new Hidden Operating System, which per the requirements "will create two TrueCrypt volumes (outer and hidden) within the first partition behind the system partition.", which is E, so I need the OS installed on C right?

Comment: @user231750 - Can you provid a screnshot paritions created by TrueCrypt ( if partitions are created that is ).  Anyways I was going to suggest inreasing C to 15GB duplicating what you did before and see if the os now sees 15Gb.  If that happens your selection the wrong partition.

Comment: Just made it a 15GB partition @Ramhound. The hidden OS partition is then 15GB. TrueCrypt seems to default to making the hidden OS partition exactly the same size as the system partition. Is there any way to change that?

Answer (score 1):

It seems my message is too late, but I drop it anyway. TrueCrypt hidden volume by definition is always equal system volume. It cannot be changed. Still there is way to use all your HDD space. You might create three partitions: first two for the decoy and hidden OS. Then you create HIDDEN TrueCrypt volume inside third partition and automount it when Hidden OS starts. In this volume you could keep “Program Files” or even move “User Profile” there.